# direction angle computation from surface normal(nx, ny, nz)

Tags: matlab, normals, point-clouds

I'd like to calculate direction angle from suface normal vector it has nx, ny, nz.

I've got 3D point clouds normals using princomp() on Matlab.

Each point has a normal vector(nx, ny, nz).

How can I compute the direction angle of normal vector?

My final goal is to plot range image colors are mapped in directional angle of surface normal.

Comment: Your first Stack Overflow question! It's written pretty well. I added the MATLAB tag for. you. One criticism: the last sentence is ungrammatical and a little confusing to me. But somebody who knows more about MATLAB and point-clouds might not have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, the direction angle means the angle of the surface normal w.r.t the surface. (Please clarify if I am interpreting it wrongly) In that case, you can take a point on the surface (or the point corresponding to the surface normal). Let the point be P (px, py, pz)'. The normal is N (nx, ny, nz)'
Let theta be the angle b/w the surface normal and the point.

cos(theta) = P.N / |P|.|N|

so in matlab,

cos_theta = P' * N / (norm(P) * norm(N))
theta = acosd(cos_theta)